# Taking integral closure

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $B$ be a finitely generated $A$ algebra, both domains. Is the integral closure of $A$ in $B$ a finite $A$ module?

I think we can show that the integral closure is again a finitely generated $A$ algebra. But I couldn’t prove it.